# Import macro to excel using open xml c#

Tags: c#, vba, openxml

I am able to copy a vbaproject part from xlsm to another xlsm through memory stream and add it through addnew part. Is there any possibility to import/add only the bas file into the xlsm file using open xml.
Can some one assist.Below code helped to take a clone of vba part and update the same.

```
private static void cloneVbaPart(string src, string dst)
{
    using (WordprocessingDocument srcDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(src, false))
    {
        var vbaPart = srcDoc.MainDocumentPart.VbaProjectPart;
        using (WordprocessingDocument dstDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(dst, true))
        {
            var partsToRemove = new List<OpenXmlPart>();
            foreach (var part in dstDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartsOfType<VbaProjectPart>())
            {
                partsToRemove.Add(part);
            }
            foreach (var part in dstDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetPartsOfType<CustomizationPart>())
            {
                partsToRemove.Add(part);
            }
            foreach (var part in partsToRemove)
            { dstDoc.MainDocumentPart.DeletePart(part); }
            var vbaProjectPart = dstDoc.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<VbaProjectPart>();
            var vbaDataPart = vbaProjectPart.AddNewPart<VbaDataPart>();
            using (Stream data = vbaPart.GetStream())
            {
                vbaProjectPart.FeedData(data);
            }
            using (Stream data = vbaPart.VbaDataPart.GetStream())
            {
                vbaDataPart.FeedData(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but i do not understand a word, can you please add more details tx

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/programmatic-access-to-office-vba-project-is-denied-960d5265-6592-9400-31bc-b2ddfb94b445